# How to properly call a inline js function from an external js function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a js function in my external js file,

```
function RefreshGrids() {
        BindPlanGrid();
    }
```

and also i have a js function in my page (inline)

```
<script>
    function BindPlanGrid() {
        Post("casesheet.aspx/BindPlanGrid", "{}", "BindPlanGrid", true);-->invoke a webmethod in the same page
    }
</script>
```

is this possible??..
sorry for correction .i mean 
is it possible to call my function from external js

Comment: js inside style tag??

Comment: Try change Style to script tag, and see the magic

Comment: sorry for the currection..

Answer (score 0):

first you try `<script type="text/javascript">alert("2");</script>`

This attribute is optional. Since Netscape 2, the default programming language in all browsers has been JavaScript. In XHTML, this attribute is required and unnecessary. In HTML, it is better to leave it out. The browser knows what to do.

```
<script>
    function BindPlanGrid() {
        Post("casesheet.aspx/BindPlanGrid", "{}", "BindPlanGrid", true);-->invoke a webmethod in the same page
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `<script>` tags. `<style>` tags are for css

```
<script>
    function BindPlanGrid() {
        Post("casesheet.aspx/BindPlanGrid", "{}", "BindPlanGrid", true);-->invoke a webmethod in the same page
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<script>` tag is what you are looking for.

```
<script>
    function BindPlanGrid() {
        Post("casesheet.aspx/BindPlanGrid", "{}", "BindPlanGrid", true);-->invoke a webmethod in the same page
    }
</script>
```